# PHP array syntax (Hacking a wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, plugins

I know it's not the best practice, but currently hacking at the Wordress Plugin 'Facet WP' to include some custom functionality. All has been working fine, however I've hit an issue with my understanding concerning PHP syntax.

How do I include my query arguments

```
            'query_args' => array(
                'meta_key' => '_custom_post_meta',
                'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'ASC',
            )
```

in the form of:

```
           $this->query_args['orderby'] = 'post__in';
```

I'm unfamiliar with the different ways of writing arrays.

The context is that I'm improving the onload search 'default' sort to immediately sort by my custom post meta, rather than but the Wordpress 'post__in' method (which sorts by ascending post IDs).

Thanks.

Edit with more code?

A basic version of the full search

function get_sort_options() {

```
      $options = array(
            'default' => array(
                'label' => __( 'Sort by', 'fwp' ),
                'query_args' => array()
            ),
)
```

The current full 'default' results sort.

```
  // Sort the results by relevancy
        if ( $this->is_search && 'default' == $sort_value ) {
             $this->query_args['orderby'] = 'post__in';
        }
```

My desired query arguments for the latter:

```
'meta_key' => '_custom_post_meta'
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
'order' => 'ASC'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a multidimensional array which can be accessed as follows:

```
$options['default']['query_args']['orderby'] = 'post__in';
$options['default']['query_args']['other'] = 'config';
```

Comment: Why not just ask for more explanation instead of giving an answer that might not be the solution?

Comment: because of `'query_args' =>` indicates that it is inside an array ;)

Comment: I have added more code, hope that helps? However essentially all I want is the syntax for expanding your answer to include more than one argument in the array: something like $whatever['query_args']['orderby'] = 'post__in' && ['other'] = 'config';